# what does delimiter in list_blobs of blockblobservice do?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

As the blockblobservice got deprecated I am unable to find documentation about the list_blobs in the older version. please help me.

like in this documentation [baseblobservice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.baseblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#list-blobs-container-name--prefix-none--num-results-none--include-none--delimiter-none--marker-none--timeout-none-) the description about the delimiter attribute is similar to prefix I am unable to find the difference between these.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have edited please check once.

Comment: Is your question about how to use delimiter in the new SDK?

Comment: yes exactly. in the new SDK, there is no delimiter so I am unable to understand its functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 12.x of Azure Storage Python SDK is drastically different than the previous versions. In a way the equivalent of `BaseBlobService` in the previous SDK is [`BlobServiceClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python) in the new SDK.

To list the blobs inside a blob container with custom delimiter, you would need to use [`walk_blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#walk-blobs-name-starts-with-none--include-none--delimiter--------kwargs-) method of [`ContainerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python) and that has a `delimiter` parameter. If this parameter is omitted, the default value of `/` is used.